# hive ouput sorted values in a each partition

Tags: sorting, hive, hiveql, partition, balanced-groups

I have two tables with schema

table: run1

```
id                      string                                      
week_date               string                                      
metric                  double
```

table: run2

```
id                      string                                      
metric                  double                                      
week_date               string                                      
statistic               int                                         

Partition Information          
col_name              data_type               comment             
week_date               string                                      
statistic               int
```

I would like to group the data in to equal sizes for each week date and then write the contents to a new table which is partitioned based on the week date as well the statistic(Statistic is nothing but the bucket id).

I find that the query partitions results correctly however the contents within a partition are not sorted

Below is the query I am using and the data I am using as well as the output from one of the partitions

Query:

```
insert overwrite table run2 partition(week_date, statistic) select id,metric, week_date, ntile(3) over (PARTITION BY week_date order by metric) as statistic from run1 distribute by week_date sort by metric desc;
```

Input:

```
B0001   2015-01-08      200.0
B0002   2015-01-08      200.0
B0003   2015-01-08      800.0
B0004   2015-01-08      600.0
B0005   2015-01-08      5400.0
B0006   2015-01-08      1100.0
B0007   2015-01-08      100.0
B0008   2015-01-08      300.0
```

Output of Partition: week_date=2015-01-08/statistic=2

```
B0003^A800.0
B0008^A300.0
B0004^A600.0
```

I was expecting the contents to be sorted by the metric value, however it is not. If I do not insert results to another table and just do a simple select I do see that the contents are indeed sorted. Is there something special that needs to be done when performing inserts?